# Display Attribute in Appended HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes

I'm trying to get a custom attribute and append it after an element. My client is using Squarespace, so we're limited in what we can manually insert with code.
This is sample HTML for a product div, and we're trying to append something that says "+ More Colors" if the value for `data-variant-option-color` exceeds **12 characters.**

**HTML from product snippet**

```
<div class="ProductList-item hentry" data-variant-option-color="Shade,Brown,Fog,Black,Emily Alaska">
```

I've been trying to use code from a similar project, but I'm not having any luck.

**Current Code (Not Working)**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.ProductList-item').each(function(){
  var colorNum = $(this).getAttribute('data-variant-option-color'));
$(this).append('<div class="more-colors">' + colorNum + '</div>');
});
});
</script>
```

I know I'm also missing an if statement, where the `more-colors` piece is only displayed when `data-variant-option-color` exceeds 12 characters.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, sorry for any confusion. I am trying to basically display "+ More Colors" beneath the .hentry item if the attribute data-variant-option-color is longer than 12 characters. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate, but to fetch the amount of characters in the data attribute you've set you can do:

`$( this).attr('data-variant-option-color' ).length`

**Edit:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ProductList-item').each(function(){
    var moreColorsElem = document.createElement( 'div' );
    moreColorsElem.classList.add( 'more-colors' );
    if ( $( this).attr('data-variant-option-color' ).length > 12 ) { 
      moreColorsElem.append( '+ More Colors' );
      this.append( moreColorsElem );
    }     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProductList-item hentry" data-variant-option-color="Shade,Brown,Fog,Black,Emily Alaska">
```

Comment: I am trying to basically display "+ More Colors" beneath the .hentry item if the attribute data-variant-option-color is longer than 12 characters. Does that make sense?